# MySQL INSERT... SELECT column count and virtual/aliased columns

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, subquery

I'm trying to insert using a select statement. However, I need to order the sub-select results using a ranking equation. If I create an alias, it throws off the column count. Can I somehow order my results using an equation?

```
INSERT INTO draft
  ( fk_contrib_id , end_time )
    SELECT pk_contrib_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), (X+Y+Z) AS ranking
    FROM contrib
    ORDER BY ranking DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

I need the 'ranking' column for sorting, but if I do, the column count is off for the insert. Do I have to use two queries for this?

Comment: Does `ORDER BY (X+Y+Z)` not work?

Comment: I think I've been coding too long. That seems like a perfectly reasonable solution. Thanks shree.pat18, sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change your query to directly use the expression in the `ORDER BY` clause, like so:

```
INSERT INTO draft
( fk_contrib_id , end_time )
SELECT pk_contrib_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
FROM contrib
ORDER BY (X+Y+Z) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the expression from the SELECT list. And use the expression in the ORDER BY clause.

```
  ORDER BY X+Y+Z
```

It's perfectly valid to ORDER BY expressions that are not in the SELECT list.